# How to check if Globalize has used a fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, globalize

I am using:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.2'
```

In my Image.rb model I have two columns I want translate (English and German):

```
translates :name, :description
```

In application.rb I set:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

Everthing works fine. I have an English description and if I change language to German it shows the German description in case there is one, otherwise the English text. Proplem is that still most image description do not have a German translation, so I would like to add a text message to the German sites saying that currently there is no German translation but we show the English text until there is a German translation available.

I planned to add into my view somthing like

```
if fallback.true?
  Message: This text has not been translated yet and is shown in English
```

Is there a way to check if Globalize has used the fallback option and display a message in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Globalize adds a [`translated_locales`](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/38443bcd07da78b7b8a9433e4c6c32dd51f964a3/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb#L4) method to instances of the translated model.

`translated_locales` returns an array of all available locales for a specific instance. When this array doesn't include the current `I18n.locale` then the fallback will be used.

You can used that like this:

```
<%= image.name %>
<%= image.description %>

<% unless image.translated_locales.include?(I18n.locale) %>
  Message: This text has not been translated yet and is shown in English
<% end %>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks.